# Is there a way to view all colliders in a unity project at runtime (after the game have been deployed)?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, debugging

I'm have created a small `Unity` project but physics has weird behavior (bug). Unfortunately it only happens on some specific hardware (after build), not on development machine.

I don't know what is the reason it's probably due to different framerate. Viewing all object and their colliders would probably help me a lot.

Is there a possibility in `Unity` to view all colliders in the game at run time (some kind of debug mode). Something similar as `Game` tab view in Unity with `Gizmos` option enabled, but for all objects ?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in that'll allow you to view gizmos in a released game. However, you can create your own debugging viewer by using the [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html).

Personally I would create something like a `DrawBounds` method that accepts the [`Bounds`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) property of the collider.